# is calling window.indexedDB.open() with every transaction wasteful

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to write a API to handle my indexedDB functionality. I am having trouble storing the db object in a class, because I have to wait for the `.onsuccess` events from the [.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBEnvironment) request to fire.

So I wrote a method to initialize the db:

```
async initializeDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const {
        dbVersion,
        databaseName,
        fieldsObjectStoreName,
        filedObjectStoreKeyName
      } = IndexDbParams;
      // Open a connection to indexDB
      const DbOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open(databaseName, dbVersion);
      DbOpenRequest.onsuccess = e => {
        const db = DbOpenRequest.result;
        // Create data stores if none exist
        if (db.objectStoreNames.length < 1) {
          if (db.objectStoreNames.indexOf(fieldsObjectStoreName) < 0) {
            db.createObjectStore(fieldsObjectStoreName, {
              keyPath: filedObjectStoreKeyName
            });
          }
        }
        // return db object, will come hore from onupgradeneeded as well
        resolve(db);
      };
      // If we need to upgrade db version
      DbOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = e => {
        const db = event.target.result;
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore(fieldsObjectStoreName, {
          keyPath: filedObjectStoreKeyName
        });
      };
    });
  }
```

Which I would then call at the beginning of all my other methods, for example:

```
async getData() {
   this.initializeDB().then(db => {
     // do stuff with the db object
   })
}
```

My question is - is this wasting a lot more resources than calling `.open()` once, and then storing it in global state? What (if any) could be the possible consequences of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not wasteful.

All my projects look something like this:

```
function openDb() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = indexedDB.open();
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
  });
}

function doSomeDbAction() {
  openDb().then(function(db) {
     // do stuff with db
  }).catch(console.warn).finally(function(db) {
    if(db) db.close();
  });
}

function doAnotherDbAction() {
  openDb().then(function(db) {
     // do more stuff with db
  }).catch(console.warn).finally(function(db) {
    if(db) db.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any comparison between storing a db objet in memory vs. the latency opening a new .open() request causes?

Comment: Nothing ready to show. But I suppose it would not be too hard to create something yourself.